# Measuring time in assembler in anylogic, question clarification

Tags: time, anylogic

Im trying to get the time in a assembler in anylogic, I can use measuretimestart/end features for the services and I can get the distribution graphs, however when I try to get the time for the assembler with the following code: **On enter 3:** Time=time(); and  **On exit:** timeDS.add(time()-Time); the mean doesn't make sense to me.  I really don't know at this stage what element is providing a realistic information in the software.
I'm testing with a 10 weeks delay time each block and no delays in the queues, even removing the selectOutput function. the arrival is a rate of 1 per month, triggering a calls for inject 1 element each, but I wet this non sense mean every time, is there any code to use in this particular situations or how I get the distributions correct?
Thanks!
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Sa7E.png)

Comment: Yes this answer my question.

Answer (score 1):

what are you trying to measure: the time it takes for the assembly to happen? The time it takes from the moment the first part of the assembly arrives until the assembly happens? This answer is only associated to the delay time.

Time seems to be a global variable, so if many assemblies are happening at the same time, your result will be distorted because Time variable changes every time an assembly starts...

Also, the on enter 3 is not what defines the moment in which the assembly process starts. Instead use the "on enter delay" action

you need to define an agent type that will be at the output of the assembler and assign it a time variable then on the "on enter delay" you can do agent.startTime=time() and the "on at exit" you can do "data.add(time()-agent.startTime)

Comment: Hello thanks for your answer, I have done several tests and the time measured with this piece of code is quite different to the one made with

Comment: Hello thanks for your answer!, and yes! what I want to know is how much time takes to the assembly to happen?, I have done several tests and the time measured with this piece of code is quite different to the one made with timemeasurestart/end feature which looks like a bit more precise, the thing is I don't know form where is getting the sum data, which is always bigger than the one used by the code, my belief is that the timemeasure feature is kind of accumulating steps or records while in the piece of code only counts the ones in the block so that's the reason the mean is so different.

Comment: the position of yoru timemeasure blocks have nothing to do with your calculation on the assembly.. you are comparing oranges with apples...  your timemeasure is calculating the time in the service blocks... why should they be similar to your assembly block.. it doesn't make sense what you are asking for here

Comment: Hi fully agree with you!,  I noticed that the max values are similar or equal to the time delay I set up to in the service and assembler blocks, so, that means the code is reflecting the time I'm setting up, and the mean is calculated between a value of 0 in the minimum and the maximal value recorded, so I would like to know where or how to set up to avoid the reading from  0 to 1 or something similar and start reading from or probably from the minimal value set up in the distribution i'm using in the time delay of the blocks.

Comment: Hello, sorry to read that,  well yes I'm really confused on how to use this software, but stating that my background is not computers science, and I really don't have any set of data to  evaluate my results, I just trying to simulate an office with three engineers receiving requests at the same time, two of them  work in independent task and the third needs the two previous tasks to assemble its own task.  i need to add some kind of inspection point to reject some tasks that will go back to the engineers, what I need to do know is how much time takes the engineers to make its task.

Comment: But also answer questions like what if they got more tasks arriving, how much is the total time and how is affected if more tasks arrive or are rejected, what if they can drop the taks via timeout function? I'm naming the task to the parts or agents going through the system